# Kendo UI Grid - Set width of Hierarchy column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a kendo ui grid in an MVC4 application like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridResultItemViewModel>()  
                .Columns(columns =>
                      columns.Bound(b => b.Distance).Width(35);
                      columns.Bound(b => b.Height).Width(35);
                      ...)
                .ClientDetailTemplateId("wellResultDetailsTemplate")
                .Name("ResultGrid"); // etc.
```

I can't figure out a way to set the width of the hierarchical/detail expander column.

Setting width or max-width in css for the .k-hierarchy-cell doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the `k-hierarchy-col` CSS class:

```
.k-grid .k-hierarchy-col {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/abason/1/edit